# Remove special characters python data frame

Tags: python

I wanted to remove special characters from a column and some words I choose.

```
df['tweet_text'][0]
'\\": \\"#\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 TEXAS Corona update 19-MAY-21\\\\n\\\\nTotal Deaths 51","180\\\\n\\\\nhttps://t.co/jeoAqC07Oq\\\\n\\\\n#\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588updates #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588 #\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\\\u2588\\"","\\"'
```

I used

```
df['tweet_text'] = df['tweet_text'].str.replace('[#,@,&,{,},",:,//,\\\n,-,\\\\,u2588]', '')
```

'  TEXAS Corona pdate 19MAY1nnTotal Deaths 110nnhttpst.cojeoAqC07Oqnn      pdates    '

As you can see in the out put, there "nn" not removed, and every "u" is removed .
Can you help me figure this out? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`.replace()` uses regular expressions. Your regex character class `'[#,@,&,{,},",:,//,\\\n,-,\\\\,u2588]'` is parsed as

```
[#,@,&,{,},",:,//,\
,-,\\,u2588]
```

so it will match the newline character and the characters `"#&,/258:@\u{}` (not a dash, though, since it's a range delimiter in regexps).

You'll need to read up on the syntax for regular expressions.

(However, if your dataframe has a string like that to begin with, I'm afraid your data is broken in other ways too...)

Comment: thats the kinda of data I get in the RDD part files, is there a possible solution to deal with broken data from the stream input?

Comment: What are "RDD part files"?

Comment: The stream creates a folder for each mini-batch of data every 3 secondes.Inside the folder there is a data file named part-* and it contains the tweets. The format of this files is RDD (Resilient Distributed Datasets)

Comment: I think you'll need to look at the code that streams the tweets.

Comment: I only used 
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("host", port)
lines.saveAsTextFiles("path")